# Rotate image and thumb

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-processing, rotation, thumbnails

I Want To Rotate image. I save My Image in Database

```
var fileInDB = GetFileFromDB();
var inputStream = new MemoryStream(fileInDB.FileData); // fileInDB.FileData is Byte[]
var image = Image.FromStream(streamInput);
image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
image.Save(streamOut, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
SaveFileToDB(streamOut.ToArray());
```

image rotate correctly. but its thumbnail dont rotate. it is code of create Thumb:

```
var fileInDB = GetFileFromDB();
var mainImage = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(fileInDB.Filedata));
int thumbWidth = 100;
int thumbHeight = (thumbWidth * mainImage.Height) / mainImage.Width;
var thumbImage = mainImage.GetThumbnailImage(thumbWidth, thumbHeight, null, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Comment: When you get the image from the DB is that in the correct layout before you create the thumbnail. Attempting to confirm the file is getting saved properly.

Comment: read and save method work properly.